# Create a submit button which will calculate a shipping and handling

Tags: javascript

I need this code to calculate the sales tax when you hit the submit button and I can't get it to work. I need to figure out how to connect it to the function. Can someone please point out where I am going wrong? I am very new at this and am wondering what I am doing wrong with my code. This is homework, I am not looking for the answer I just need someone to direct me in the right way.Thanx
My assignment is:

Many companies normally charge a shipping and handling fee for
purchases. Create a Web page that allows a user to enter a purchase
price into a text box; include a JavaScript function that calculates
shipping and handling. Add functionality to the script that adds a
minimum shipping and handling fee of $1.50 for any purchase that is
less than or equal to $25.00. For any orders over $25.00, add 10% to
the total purchase price for shipping and handling, but do not include
the $1.50 minimum shipping and handling fee. Th e formula for calculating
a percentage is price * percent / 100. For example, the formula
for calculating 10% of a $50.00 purchase price is 50 * 10 / 100, which
results in a shipping and handling fee of $5.00. After you determine
the total cost of the order (purchase plus shipping and handling),
display it in an alert dialog box.

Here is my Code: I need this code to calculate the sales tax when you hit the submit button and I can't get it to work.  Can someone please point out where I am going wrong?

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA [*/ 
//Shipping & handling fee 

var price=[];
var shipping=calculateShipping(price);
var total=price+shipping;

function calculateShipping()
{  
  var num = new Number(price); 
 //This will add $1.50 to any purchases that are less than or equal to $25.00. 
if (num <= 25){   
  return 1.5; 
//Here 10% will be added to any purchase that is greater than $25.00 but do not inlcude the     

$1.50 fee. 
} else{   
  return num * 10 / 100;  
}  
}  
window.alert("Your total is $" + total + ".")  

/* ]]> */ 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Enter Purchase Price Here</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */

document.write(parseFloat");
if(price <=25.00){var shipping=1.50}
else{var shipping=price*(10/100)};

var total=(price+shipping).toFixed(2);


/* ]]> */
</script>


<form id="btncalcprice" action="submit-form.php">
<input type='text' name='query'>
</form>

<form>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="alert('YOUR total is $'); return true">

</form>
</body>
```

Comment: I see a function that is lonely.

Comment: I would suggest leveraging a JavaScript framework like JQuery... it'll make most any task (even simple ones) in JavaScript a lot more pleasant. Also, `return false;` (or `preventDefault()`) is what you do if you don't want the event to do the normal action, not `return true`.

Comment: First off, you might want to look at your onClick event when you click the submit button.  At no time do you call your Javascript.  What you did post most certainly is not calculating sales tax let alone adding anything up.  You might want to check where you got your code from because it appears some is missing.

Comment: okay Ifixed that issue.  I added my assignment so you can see what I am trying to do.  I have to use a submit button which will calculate the shipping and handling and sent the results to a alert box.   Thank you for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Reviewed Code

You have some syntax issues in your code, additionally the methodology you were following was not quite correct. You need to call the function from the button onclick event, then run your JavaScript. You will find what you need in the updated code example below. Make note that I used parseFloat instead of parseInt in order to incorporate decimals...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA [*/ 
function calculateShipping() {
    var price = document.getElementById('price').value;
    //This will add $1.50 to any purchases that are less than or equal to $25.00. 
    if (price <= 25){   
        price=parseFloat(price) + 1.5;    
    } else {
        //add 10%
        var percentToAdd=parseFloat(price) * .1;
        price=parseFloat(price)+parseFloat(percentToAdd);
    }
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML='Total shipping cost: '+price;
}  

/* ]]> */ 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Enter Purchase Price Here</h1>

<div id="result"></div>
<input type="text" name="price" id="price">
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="calculateShipping(); return false;">

</body>
```

First of all you dont need the form action if you are just calling a function, secondly if you want to prevent the default submit of the form, then return false in your onclick... it should look like this:

onclick="calculateShipping(); return false;"